# Flutter Dropdown Menu details not saving to firestore

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

// I have been trying to make the selected users in my dropdown menu save to firestore but it's not saving. here is the important part of my code
     I think all the major code is present already
 // I actually stored some information with firestore instance document recently but seems I don't know how to use for drop down menu

```
    User selectedUser;    
      List<User> users = <User>[const User('Normal User'),const User('Senior'),const User('Junior'), const User('Admin')];

    }

    new DropdownButton<User>(
                  value: selectedUser,
                onChanged: (User newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedUser = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: users.map((User user) {
                  return new DropdownMenuItem<User>(

                    value: user,
                    child: new Text(
                      user.name,
                    ),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
                  Future sendData() async{

Firestore.instance.collection('Profession').document()
  .setData({ 'selectedUser': selectedUser,
    })  
  .catchError((error) {
    print('error: $error');
    return null;
  });
```

Comment: You are not giving callbacks for the future to use after completion: `setData({}).then(function() {
    console.log("Success");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error: ", error);
});`

Comment: I don't really understand your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After over two days of battling with the problem. I was finally able to make the information of the dropdown button in this code store directly to firestore by replacing all **User** with **String**

Answer (score 0):

To get more information about operation status you should provide callback methods for the [promise object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) returned by `setData` like this:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('Profession').document()
  .setData({ 'selectedUser': selectedUser,
    })
  .then(function() { console.log("Success"); }) 
  .catch(function(error) { console.error("Error: ", error)});
```

Comment: got this error message I/flutter (15333): error: Invalid argument: Instance of 'User'

Comment: Now you have an error message. Could you post how 'Profession' collection looks like? Are you sure your input structure to `setData` matches the this collection structure?

Comment: User selectedUser;
  List<User> users = <User>[const User('Normal User'),const User('P'),const User('F S'), const User('R S')];

Comment: value: selectedUser,
            onChanged: (User newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selectedUser = newValue;
              });
            },
            items: users.map((User user) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<User>(

                value: user,
                child: new Text(


                 
                  user.name,

Comment: I can't deduce much from your comments. To make it easier for others to help you please try to edit the post and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When is `selectedUser` assigned? Unfortunately you still need to post more information.

Comment: SelectedUser is assigned to newvalue